# Can not install Terraform: The requested URL returned error: 405

Tags: terraform

I am installing Terraform from https://www.terraform.io/cli/install/apt, but I get the below error

`The requested URL returned error: 405`. I live in Russia, is this because of sanctions? or I missied something?

Environment:
Ubuntu 20.04 (focal)

Comment: If you have VPN try using one.

Comment: Worked with VPN cool thanks @MiguelConde

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can use the links to the terraform binary on [Yandex Cloud documentation](https://cloud.yandex.ru/docs/tutorials/infrastructure-management/terraform-quickstart#from-yc-mirror). You can download the binary file and use it.

Answer (score 0):

Try to install brew package manager

```
1: $ sudo apt-get install build-essential procps curl file git -y
2: $ /bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/install.sh)"
3: $ echo 'eval "$(/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/bin/brew shellenv)"' >> /home/$USER/.profile
eval "$(/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/bin/brew shellenv)"
4: $ brew update
```

Then try to install Terraform

---

- for **Installation** - `brew install terraform`
- for **Upgrade** - `brew upgrade terraform`
- for **Verification** - `terraform --version`

---